# AngularFire valueChanges not working on deletions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I am using Angular 9, Firebase 7.14.3, AngularFire 6, and NgRx 9.

I have a calendar of appointments that I want to update automatically anytime my Firestore database changes, without needing to refresh the page. Right now it is only half working. Adding appointments manually in the database will automatically update the browser accordingly, manually deleting in the database does not.

When logging the incoming data in `ngOnChanges`, anytime I manually add an appointment, it logs the data I expect. It shows that `currentValue` has the new appointment and `previousValue` doesn't, but when I delete an appointment, `currentValue` and `previousValue` are exactly the same. It clearly recognizes that data has changed, since `ngOnChanges` logs to the console, but the `currentValue` array is still showing the deleted appointment for some reason.

I have an Effect that looks like this:

```
@Effect()
loadAppointments$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(appointmentsActions.LOAD_APPOINTMENTS),
    map((action: appointmentsActions.LoadAppointments) => action.payload),
    switchMap(data => {
        const { companyId, startDate, endDate } = data;
        return this.afs
            .collection('companies')
            .doc(companyId)
            .collection<Appointment>('appointments', ref => {
                return ref
                    .where('startTimeMs', '>=', startDate)
                    .where('startTimeMs', '<=', endDate);
            })
            .valueChanges()
            .pipe(
                map(
                    appointments =>
                        new appointmentsActions.LoadAppointmentsSuccess(appointments),
                ),
                catchError(error =>
                    of(new appointmentsActions.LoadAppointmentsFail(error)),
                ),
            );
    }),
);
```

Is this a bug with Firebase or AngularFire? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: To make this a little weirder, If I delete from the browser, it works as I'd hope, but only in the browser that I deleted it from. If I have the app running in two browsers, it doesn't update in the other one. One browser shows that `currentValue` has the expected data, and the other browser logs a "new" `currentValue` to the console too, but it still has the deleted appointment as part of the data.

However, if I add a new appointment, both browsers update accordingly.

Comment: There isnt enough info to investigate this issue. The `effect` code is for load. Whats not working is the `delete`. YOu need to provide code for how the `delete` call is made from component and what are the effects for that action.  |||||||||| Also, why would you need `ngOnChanges` when you have selectors ?  What are the parent and child components. This question cant be answered with provided details

Comment: What is happening in appointmentsActions.LoadAppointmentsSuccess?